# Plupload server assigned file name

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, file-upload, plupload

I'm using plupload to upload multiple files at once. I want to assign unique filenames on the serverside, and store it to backend during single file upload. (Storage has a flat namespace)

I want to generate a filename on the server backend, and pass this back to the client, in order for the client to post the full form, which includes a list of uploaded files (with appropriate filenames).

I am using the plupload [queue widget](http://www.plupload.com/example_queuewidget.php) example, but this appears to have a bug for multiple files with the same name. If I upload three files with the exact same name, the POST data on form submit will have three identical filenames, even though the upload.php in the example implementation (from zip file) renames the files to be file, file_1 and file_2.

How can I send this filename back to plupload in order to identify the file from form submit (with the upload_1_name post data)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set *unique_names* to **true** in your configuration. This will:

> "...generate unqiue filenames for the files so that they don't for
>   example collide with existing ones on the server."

Comment: This doesn't answers the OP question on how to send file name from server-side to Plupload.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$filePath = $targetDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . md5(microtime()).$fileName;
```

Comment: Please include a description of what your code does. Code-only answers are not usually helpful to those people who need to ask the question in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

To make the filenames unique, I used this code:

```
$filePath = $targetDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . uniqid().$fileName;
```

`uniqid()` is a shorter way of saying `md5(microtime())`.